# Why binary search not find my string?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, binary-search

I have an ordered txt file like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

I want to check if "ddd" string exists in the file...

Here my func:

```
- (BOOL) asd:(NSString*)sting 
{
NSArray *LinesCount = 
  [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"longfile.txt"  
   encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil]   
    componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];

unsigned index = (unsigned)CFArrayBSearchValues(
                 (CFArrayRef)LinesCount, 
                 CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount((CFArrayRef)LinesCount)),
                 (CFStringRef)string, 
                 (CFComparatorFunction)CFStringCompare, 
                 NULL);
if (index < [LinesCount count]) return YES;
return NO;
}
```

Why does it always returns NO, with any string?

Comment: Your file is tooooo large but you load it every time when you need to search string??

Comment: And do you know that bsearch can return `index < [LinesCount count]` but `LinesCount` won't have that string?

Comment: @Nekto i don't load file every times... it's a simple snippet to show the problem! Have you an idea to fix it?

Comment: Does `LinesCount` contain any object?

Comment: Have you verified that the array "LinesCount" actually has more than one entry and that it has at least one entry greater than the search string?  Also could it be an encoding problem, take a look at the actual data values.

Comment: LineCount contains all objects. Strings are cleaned, without any \n or \r. But it cannot recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you read in the array.
If you replace the code that assigns `LineCount` with

```
NSArray * LinesCount = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", @"ccc", @"ddd", @"eee", nil];
```

you will see the binary search performs fine.

There are two issues in your code:

- Line separator is probably just "\n" if the file has been created on Mac OS X
- Your array will contain a left over "" as it's last element hence the requirement for ordering as required by CFArrayBSearchValues is no longer satisfied.

As an example:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [@"one\ntwo\n" componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]);
```

yields (note the last empty element):

```
 2011-09-29 16:52:33.024 a.out[4019:707] (
     one,
     two,
     ""
 )
```

Comment: Great! This is the problem! The last string in my files was ""! Thanks a lot!!